# iOS 11-12 large title background image for large state

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set different colors for different navigation bar large title states. For base large title state(when it's large and not scrolled) bar should have grayColor(i am setting barTint color), but when the user scrolls content and bar is attached to top(goes to UIBarPosition.topAttached) it should have white color, so I am setting background image for .topAttached state, and because of that image my barTint color is ignored.

I've tried to set background image for all possible nav bar UIBarPosition's and UIBarMetrics, and for topAttached state image work's well, but for large state it never appeared. Example:

```
bar.setBackgroundImage(.pixel(color: UIColor.red), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
bar.setBackgroundImage(.pixel(color: UIColor.green), for: .topAttached, barMetrics: .default)
bar.setBackgroundImage(.pixel(color: UIColor.blue), for: .bottom, barMetrics: .default)
bar.setBackgroundImage(.pixel(color: UIColor.purple), for: .top, barMetrics: .default)
```

Is there any way to make different colors for different large title states in iOS 11-12?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution, works for iOS 11-12:

```
 let observer = navBar.observe(\.frame, changeHandler: { (bar, frame) in
            if navBar.frame.height <= 44 {
                navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
                navBar.shadowImage = imageForShadow
            }
            else {
                navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
                navBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            }
        })
```